# Explain jQuery code sample

Tags: jquery

I inherited the following jQuery code snippet as part of a jquery/AJAX validation system.  I simply need someone to explain the code line by line with comments so I may understand how to change a few actions of the script:

```
// Use Ajax to send everything to form processing file
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $(form).slideUp("slow");
        $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Specifically, the lines re 'success . . . ' are of particular interest to me, because I can see that $(form).slideUp("slow") causes the form to slide up slowly (kinda obvious, no?).  The 'slideUP' action does not take me to the top of the form, but always somewhere in the middle of the form.  If I understand the jQuery a bit better, I might figure out how to make 'slideUp' always take me to the top of the form.

Comment: if you just need to know what that code does, a good place to start is the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: If you read the documentation for [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp), you'll see it simply rolls up the element and doesn't change the scroll bar position in anyway; you'll want [`$(window).scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) for that.

Comment: An even better place would be [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

The function is used for handling the `submit` event of a `form` element.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
```

Once you click on the send button, the value, **Send** should turn into **Sending...**:

```
    $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
```

The function `ajaxSubmit` submits the form without a page refresh to another URL.

```
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
```

After the submission, this function is called. Where the `responseText` is the text which is returned from the server. `statusText` is the HTTP Status Code. `xhr` is the `XMLHttpRequest` object used. `$form` is the `form` element that was processed.

```
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
```

Now, after submission, you are sliding the `form` up, in an animated way.

```
            $(form).slideUp("slow");
```

You are filling the `#response` div, a place where you are showing the information to the user, by sliding down smoothly.

```
        $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
```

You are stopping the form from normal HTTP submission.

```
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Praveen:  Thanx for the line-by-line explanation!

Comment: FYI, here are the [List of HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 1):

My narrative notes start with `//#`

```
// Use Ajax to send everything to form processing file

//# Create a function called 'submitHandler'
submitHandler: function(form) {

    //# Set a form field saying the form is being sent.
    $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");

    //# Using the form, sumit its value using jQuery's ajaaax
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({

        //# Should the result be successful, call this function
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            //# Slide the form into view (I believe)
            $(form).slideUp("slow");
            //# This puts the return value of the AJAX caall into #response
            $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("slow");
        }
    });

    //# I'm pretty sure that under jQuery this will stop the default action,
    //# which would be a regular form submit.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're right with everything apart from `slideUp()`; it rolls up the form. See http://api.jquery.com/slideUp

Comment: @Matt -- Ah, not too bad then.  I don't actually use jQuery but its hard not to learn how to read it around here.

Comment: Jeremy: Thanx for explanation! Matt: Thanx for the $(window).scrollTop() suggestion; that rendered the action I needed.